# Google sometimes show the "aggregate rating" rich snippet but sometimes shows the "how to" snippet instead

Tags: google, google-search, rich-snippets, structured-data, json-ld

I wrote json-dl code  "How to" structured data for some pages so they show show a list of steps in the search results.

However for some of the pages my "Aggregate Rating" structured data is used instead and Google shows the rich snippet for that.

Why happen that problem and how can I solve it?  How can I Prioritize to them?

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@type": "WebSite",
      "@id": "https://example.com/mag?lggtime=19_1578473226/#website",
      "url": "https://example.com/mag?lggtime=19_1578473226/",
      "name": "\u0645\u062c\u0644\u0647 \u062b\u0628\u062a\u200c\u06cc\u0627\u0631",
      "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "https://example.com/mag?lggtime=19_1578473226/?s={search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "@id": "https://example.com/mag/5494/%d8%aa%d9%86%d8%b8%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%82%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%af/?lggtime=19_1578473226#primaryimage",
      "url": "https://example.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Set-the-written-agreement.jpg",
      "width": 1200,
      "height": 675,
      "caption": "\u062a\u0646\u0638\u06cc\u0645 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f | \u062b\u0628\u062a \u06cc\u0627\u0631"
    },
    {
      "@type": "WebPage",
      "@id": "https://example.com/mag/5494/%d8%aa%d9%86%d8%b8%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%82%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%af/?lggtime=19_1578473226#webpage",
      "url": "https://example.com/mag/5494/%d8%aa%d9%86%d8%b8%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%82%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%af/?lggtime=19_1578473226",
      "inLanguage": "fa-IR",
      "name": "\u062a\u0646\u0638\u06cc\u0645 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f \u0628\u0627 \u062b\u0628\u062a\u200c\u06cc\u0627\u0631 \u062f\u0631 \u0633\u0631\u06cc\u0639\u200c\u062a\u0631\u06cc\u0646 \u0632\u0645\u0627\u0646 \u0645\u0645\u06a9\u0646 | \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f\u0647\u0627 | \u062b\u0628\u062a\u200c\u06cc\u0627\u0631",
      "isPartOf": {
        "@id": "https://example.com/mag?lggtime=19_1578473226/#website"
      },
      "primaryImageOfPage": {
        "@id": "https://example.com/mag/5494/%d8%aa%d9%86%d8%b8%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%82%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%af/?lggtime=19_1578473226#primaryimage"
      },
      "datePublished": "2019-08-21T11:21:39+04:30",
      "dateModified": "2019-12-24T06:15:35+03:30",
      "author": {
        "@id": "https://example.com/mag?lggtime=19_1578473226/#/schema/person/1185bb602ae3355d3a31697f6de208e3"
      },
      "description": "\u062a\u0646\u0638\u06cc\u0645 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f \u06cc\u06a9\u06cc \u0627\u0632 \u0642\u0631\u0622\u06cc\u0646\u062f\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0628\u0647 \u0634\u062f\u062a \u067e\u06cc\u0686\u06cc\u062f\u0647\u200c\u0627\u06cc\u200c\u0633\u062a \u06a9\u0647 \u0646\u06cc\u0627\u0632 \u0628\u0647 \u0632\u0645\u0627\u0646 \u0648 \u062f\u0642\u062a \u0641\u0631\u0627\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f\u060c \u0627\u0632 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u067e\u0633 \u0645\u06cc\u200c\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646\u06cc\u062f \u062a\u0646\u0638\u06cc\u0645 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f\u200c\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062e\u0648\u062f \u0631\u0627 \u0628\u0647 \u062b\u0628\u062a\u200c\u06cc\u0627\u0631 \u0628\u0633\u067e\u0627\u0632\u06cc\u062f."
    },
    {
      "@type": [
        "Person"
      ],
      "@id": "https://example.com/mag?lggtime=19_1578473226/#/schema/person/1185bb602ae3355d3a31697f6de208e3",
      "name": "\u0632\u0647\u0631\u0627 \u0627\u0633\u062f\u06cc",
      "image": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "@id": "https://example.com/mag?lggtime=19_1578473226/#authorlogo",
        "url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/527f2fbe84d19192364a9be8209b7e2a?s=96&d=mm&r=g",
        "caption": "\u0632\u0647\u0631\u0627 \u0627\u0633\u062f\u06cc"
      },
      "sameAs": []
    },
    {
      "@type": "AggregateRating",
      "ratingValue": "4.44",
      "ratingCount": "9",
      "itemReviewed": {
        "@type": "HowTo",
        "name": "\u062a\u0646\u0638\u06cc\u0645 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f \u0628\u0627 \u062b\u0628\u062a\u200c\u06cc\u0627\u0631 \u062f\u0631 \u0633\u0631\u06cc\u0639\u200c\u062a\u0631\u06cc\u0646 \u0632\u0645\u0627\u0646 \u0645\u0645\u06a9\u0646",
        "step": [
          {
            "@type": "HowToStep",
            "text": "\u062a\u0646\u0638\u06cc\u0645 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f \u062f\u0631 \u062b\u0628\u062a\u200c\u06cc\u0627\u0631"
          },
          {
            "@type": "HowToStep",
            "text": "\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u062f \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f"
          },
          {
            "@type": "HowToStep",
            "text": "\u0645\u062a\u0646 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062f"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is that Google sees the "user intent" differently, and serves the snippet accordingly.
Afaik, there's no way you can "force" google to display a rich snippet, yet alone to prioritize what it will show.